# How can I borrow PyroCMS' WYSIWYG editor for a module of my own?

Tags: javascript, fckeditor, pyrocms

I've included the following in the admin controller method (as per the `pages` admin controller):

- `admin.js`
- `CodeMirror.js`
- `wysiwyg.php` *includes some more javascript and initialises the FCKeditor*

But my `<textarea>` still doesn't have the wysiwyh controls. Can this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can apply the class "wysiwyg-simple" or "wysiwyg-advanced" to get one of the two WYSIWYG editors you see around. You do not need to include the first two.

CodeMirror is a HTML/CSS/JavaScript syntax highlighter we use in a few places, nothing to do with WYSIWYG.

Comment: Well I'd hope so. I did write the darn thing :)